# Spark data form muster

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing

I made a standalone apache cluster with 7 pcs. To run the scala code, code is

---

```
/** Our main function where the action happens */

def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // Set the log level to only print errors

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    // Create a SparkContext without much actual configuration

    // We want EMR's config defaults to be used.

    val conf = new SparkConf()

    conf.setAppName("MovieSimilarities1M")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val input = sc.textFile("file:///home/ralfahad/LearnSpark/SBTCreate/customer-orders.csv")

    val mappedInput = input.map(extractCustomerPricePairs)

    val totalByCustomer = mappedInput.reduceByKey( (x,y) => x + y )

    val flipped = totalByCustomer.map( x => (x._2, x._1) )

    val totalByCustomerSorted = flipped.sortByKey()

    val results = totalByCustomerSorted.collect()

    // Print the results.

    results.foreach(println)

  }

}
```

---

Steps are:

1. I create .jar file using sbt
2. submit the job using spark-submit *.jar

But my executor cannot locate `sc.textFile("file:///home/ralfahad/LearnSpark/SBTCreate/customer-orders.csv")`

This customer-orders.csv file is stored in my master PC.

**Full stacktrace:**

> error: [Stage 0:> (0 + 2) / 2]17/09/25 17:32:35 ERROR TaskSetManager:
>   Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job Exception in thread
>   "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage
>   failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost
>   task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 141.225.166.191, executor 2):
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: File
>   file:/home/ralfahad/LearnSpark/SBTCreate/customer-orders.csv does not
>   exist

How do I solve this issue?

Please modify the code to run in my cluster.

Comment: error: [Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]17/09/25 17:32:35 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 141.225.166.191, executor 2): java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/home/ralfahad/LearnSpark/SBTCreate/customer-orders.csv does not exist

Answer (score 0):

In order for your working nodes to be able to access the file, you have several options.

**1. Manually copy the file to all the nodes.**

Each node should have this file at exactly this path: `/home/ralfahad/LearnSpark/SBTCreate/customer-orders.csv`

**2. Submit your job with the file attached.**

`spark-submit` has an option call `--files` that allows you to copy any number of files while submitting the job like this:

```
spark-submit --master ... -jars ... --files /home/ralfahad/LearnSpark/SBTCreate/customer-orders.csv
```

Don't abuse this. This option is more intended for testing purposes and small files.

**3. Use some external universally available storage that can be accessed by all the nodes.**

S3 and NFS shares are popular choices.

```
sc.textFile("s3n://bucketname/customer-orders.csv")
```

**4. You can read the data in you driver program, then convert it do RDD for processing.**

```
val bufferedSource = io.Source.fromFile("/home/ralfahad/LearnSpark/SBTCreate/customer-orders.csv")
val lines = (for (line <- bufferedSource.getLines()) yield line).toList
val rdd = sc.makeRdd(lines)
```

Not generally recommended, but can be used for quick tests.